# How to use WHERE in CONCAT in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, concatenation

Here is my scenario as beginner in mysql.

There are 2 tables.

- *usermeta* has 3 columns *user_id, meta_key, meta value*
- *users_role* has 2 columns *uid, rid*.

I need to insert rows in *wp_usermeta* based on *users_roles.rid* value.

- *User_id* from *users_roles* (*users_role.uid* matches *wp_usermeta.user_id*).
- *Meta_key* is set to *dokan_profile_settings*.
- *Meta_value* should be a CONCAT of :

textA + *meta_value* from rows with meta_key *dokan_site_name* already existing in *wp_usermeta* + textB.

There is my problem. I can't figure out the right way to achieve the CONCAT properly.

When i run this i get : **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**

```
INSERT INTO usermeta (
    user_id, 
    meta_key, 
    meta_value
    )
SELECT
    uid,
    'dokan_profile_settings',
    CONCAT('textA', (SELECT usermeta.meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE usermeta.meta_key LIKE 'dokan_store_name'), 'textB') 
AS meta_value
FROM users_roles WHERE rid LIKE '4';
```

If i just run the SELECT part of the CONCAT, as pointed out in Paul's comment :

```
SELECT usermeta.meta_value FROM usermeta 
WHERE usermeta.meta_key LIKE 'dokan_store_name'
```

I get the intended result, but i can't figure out why the whole query fails.

Comment: What are the results if you only run the `SELECT` portion of that query by itself?

Comment: Thanks Paul, I had to add  FROM usermeta for the SELECT portion to return the intended result. The whole query now returns this error : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states, you can't use a subquery that returns more than one string value in a CONCAT() function.
An easy way to solve this would be to GROUP_CONCAT() the results of your subquery: `CONCAT('textA', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(usermeta.meta_value) FROM usermeta WHERE usermeta.meta_key LIKE 'dokan_store_name'), 'textB')`

Comment: Thanks Flo that solved it!